# Let $A \cap B = H$ and suppose that $A=a_1H \cup a_2H \cup …. \cup a_rH$ is a disjoint union.

Tags: group-theory

Let $A \cap B = H$ and suppose that  $A=a_1H \cup a_2H \cup …. \cup a_rH$ is a disjoint union. Prove that $AB=a_1B \cup a_2B \cup … \cup a_rB$ is a disjoint union.

The next part of the question is to write down and prove a formula for |AB|, which I can do but I am not sure how to do this part.

Further on in my notes my lecturer mentioned *"the general theorem that two cosets of a subgroup either coincide or are disjoint"* but doesn't state it anywhere as far as I can see, what is the more formal version of this theorem?

Thanks